# Como corrigir URL de requisição POST utilizando REST no ExtJS 4?

Tags: javascript, extjs, rest

Estou utilizando proxy REST. De acordo com o padrão, ao adicionar um dado é utilizado o POST sem nenhum parâmetro na URL. Por exemplo, se eu quiser adicionar um usuário, minha URL deve ser `localhost/usuarios/`.

Com o proxy REST do ExtJS 4, ao adicionar um novo objeto está sendo utilizado POST e URL `localhost/usuarios/0`.

Seguem as classes para exemplificar:

**Proxy**

```
Ext.define('App.proxy.MeuProxy', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.proxy.Rest',

    require: ['Ext.MessageBox'],

    alias : 'proxy.meuproxy',
    type : 'rest',

    reader : {
        type : 'json',
        messageProperty : 'msg',
        root : 'data'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json',
        writeAllFields: true,
        encode: true,
        allowSingle: true,
        root: 'data'
    }
});
```

**Store**

```
Ext.define('App.store.Usuarios', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires : ['App.model.Usuario'],

    model : 'App.model.Usuario'

});
```

**Model**

```
Ext.define('App.model.Usuario', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires : ['App.proxy.MeuProxy'],

    idProperty : 'id',
    fields : [{
        name : 'id',
        type : 'int'
    }, {
        name : 'nome',
        type : 'string'
    }, {
        name : 'sobrenome',
        type : 'string'
    }],

    proxy : {
        type : 'meuproxy',
        url : 'usuarios/'
    }
});
```

Eu estou utilizando o `getRecord()` da classe `Ext.form.Panel` para resgatar o dado do meu formulário para o modelo e, depois, `save()` da classe `Ext.data.Model` para enviar para o servidor.

```
var novoUsuario = meuFormulario.getRecord();
novoUsuario.save();
```

A solicitação enviada ao servidor vai para a URL `localhost/usuarios/0`.
O json enviado é:

```
{
    "data" : {
        "id" : 0,
        "nome" : "Maria",
        "sobrenome" : "do Socorro"
    }
}
```

Vi que, se eu não definir o tipo de ID, a saída fica como string e minha URL `localhost/usuarios/` (como eu preciso que fique), porém não é desejado pois interfere no backend, que espera um valor inteiro para id e nada na URL.

*Saída com ID do tipo auto (não definido)*:

```
{
    "data" : {
        "id" : "",
        "nome" : "Maria",
        "sobrenome" : "do Socorro"
    }
}
```

Como posso enviar a URL `localhost/usuarios/` (sem nenhum parâmetro), com método POST, e o atributo id da minha model como inteiro (`id=0`)?

Obs.: Lembrando que, em REST, a edição, exclusão e seleção de um usuário registra o seu id na URL (`localhost/usuarios/2`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com base no [código fonte da classe Ext.data.proxy.Rest](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/source/Rest.html#Ext-data-proxy-Rest), sobrescrevi o método `buildUrl()`, como segue abaixo:

```
buildUrl : function(request) {
    var me = this, operation = request.operation;

            // Se o tipo de operação for 'create' não adiciona id na URL
            me.appendId = !(operation.action === "create");

    return me.callParent(arguments);
}
```

Essa alteração cria a limitação de que o parâmetro appendId não providencia mais na extensão ou instanciação dessa classe a capacidade de incluir o id ou não na URL, pois este mecanismo passa a ser gerenciado automaticamente pela nova classe.

Answer (score 1):

No proxy REST por defaul o parametro appendId é true o que gera uma url como usuarios/1, inserindo o id automaticamente. Coloque o parametro com false.

```
proxy : {
    type : 'meuproxy',
    url : 'usuarios/',
    appendId: false // default true
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Na verdade precisava de algo que funcionasse apenas para o tipo de método POST (ou operação de 'CREATE'). Com base na sua resposta fiz a minha que postei aqui. De qualquer forma, dei um upvote pela sua ajuda.